# I keep getting builder.rimraf is not a function when i build npm

Tags: javascript, svelte, netlify, vercel, sveltekit

I am trying to make my svelteapp prodcution ready and therefor running `npm run build`
I have tried with several adapters but i keep getting the same error saying

```
> Using @sveltejs/adapter-netlify
> builder.rimraf is not a function
```

The application itself runs fine with npm run dev.

I have searched everywhere.
tried the following

- node version 16.14.0 also tried with older version and the newest 17.5.0
- Deleting node_modules and ran npm i again
- deleting package-lock.json
- tried another adapter like adapter-vercel and adapter-auto that comes with sveltekit

Comment: could you share some more details? What OS are you on? Can you share a github repo with a reproduction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like you're on an old version of `@sveltejs/adapter-netlify` that is incompatible with the latest version of SvelteKit. Try running the following to update to the latest versions of everything:

```
npm i @sveltejs/kit@next
npm i @sveltejs/adapter-netlify@next
```

Comment: Worked flawlessly, thank you

Comment: still fails with `$ npm i -D '@sveltejs/adapter-node@next'`